# adding constraints for subView (leading and trailing space to container margin) programatically in obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a SubView named "settingSubView" onto main UIView and i have added a programatically horizontal UIScrollView named "scrollView". Constraints are added to the settingSubView in storyboard. but my scroll view gets displayed outside the bounds of the settingsSubView.

My question is how do i add leading and trailing space to container margin for scrollView with respect to settingSubView progrmmatically in objective c.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to programmatically create `NSLayoutConstraint` between scrollView and settingsSubView. In this example i've set the constrain to 10.
Don't forget that when adding constrains programmatically you must set the view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint* trailConstrain=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:settingSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
NSLayoutConstraint* leadingConstrain=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:settingSubView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:10];
[scrollView addConstraints:@[trailConstrain, leadingConstrain]];
```

Some useful reading material : http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/02/20/creating-individual-layout-constraints/

Comment: I tried using the above code.On running the app , it just crashed. giving following error.
"The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fd6a143f660 UIScrollView:0x7fd6a1437900.trailing == UIView:0x7fd6a1437da0.trailing + 10>
 When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
  " Any idea why this must be happening?

Comment: it sounds like settings and scroll are siblings and not parent-child. leading and trail constrains need to be between parent-child views, so change the toItem to the parent view and add the constrains to the parent view.

Comment: Thank you ..just reduced the width of UIScrollView and it works. Thank you so much.